# How to remove css property from last child element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-selectors

This is dynamic code where i can not assign any class or id to child element and the number of child elements are not fixed as well.I can add class or id to my table and row only can't able to access code for td.I need to remove margin-right property from  the last child element of a specific table(that table is unique and i can add class or id to that table)
here is my code

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="12" border="0" class="category_list">
    <tr valign="top" height="99" class="category_list_row">
        <td class="categery-box category-right-margin"><a href="#"><img border="0" title="shop2.jpg" alt="shop2.jpg" src="#"></a>

            <div class="shop_content"><span class="shop_txt"><a onmouseout="this.className='lnk-HedOff'; return true;" onmouseover="this.className='lnk-HedOn'; return true;" ;="" class="lnk-HedOff" href="#">Laptops &amp; Notebooks</a>
    </span>
 <a onmouseout="this.className='lnk-HedOff'; return true;" onmouseover="this.className='lnk-HedOn'; return true;" ;="" class="lnk-HedOff" href="#"><input type="image" src="#"></a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="categery-box category-right-margin"><a href="/s.nl/c.3747762/sc.7/category.59/.f"><img border="0" title="ipad.jpg" alt="ipad.jpg" src="/core/media/media.nl?id=130&amp;c=3747762&amp;h=d03cb241573f0b4c67c8"></a>

            <div class="shop_content"><span class="shop_txt"><a onmouseout="this.className='lnk-HedOff'; return true;" onmouseover="this.className='lnk-HedOn'; return true;" ;="" class="lnk-HedOff" href="#">iPADs &amp; Tablets</a>
    </span>
 <a onmouseout="this.className='lnk-HedOff'; return true;" onmouseover="this.className='lnk-HedOn'; return true;" ;="" class="lnk-HedOff" href="#"><input type="image" src="#"></a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="categery-box category-right-margin"><a href="#"><img border="0" title="shop1.jpg" alt="shop1.jpg" src="#"></a>

            <div class="shop_content"><span class="shop_txt"><a onmouseout="this.className='lnk-HedOff'; return true;" onmouseover="this.className='lnk-HedOn'; return true;" ;="" class="lnk-HedOff" href="#">Mobile Phones</a>
    </span>
 <a onmouseout="this.className='lnk-HedOff'; return true;" onmouseover="this.className='lnk-HedOn'; return true;" ;="" class="lnk-HedOff" href="#"><input type="image" src="#"></a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="categery-box category-right-margin"><a href="/s.nl/c.3747762/sc.7/category.49/.f"><img border="0" title="shop3.jpg" alt="shop3.jpg" src="#"></a>

            <div class="shop_content"><span class="shop_txt"><a onmouseout="this.className='lnk-HedOff'; return true;" onmouseover="this.className='lnk-HedOn'; return true;" ;="" class="lnk-HedOff" href="#">Cameras</a>
    </span>
 <a onmouseout="this.className='lnk-HedOff'; return true;" onmouseover="this.className='lnk-HedOn'; return true;" ;="" class="lnk-HedOff" href="/s.nl/c.3747762/sc.7/category.49/.f"><input type="image" src="#"></a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How to achieve this using jquery?I want to remove margin-right property from the last td element.

Comment: use [last-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)

Comment: Can you know when the data are updated ? In this case you can simply bind a callback function when this occurs, and then use jQuery last child selector (http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)

Comment: What `margin-right` property? you mean the `.category-margin-right` or the `CSS` property?

Comment: No i dont know....Is there any way we can use the class name of that table and remove the css property from the last td?

Comment: css property i want to remove

Comment: Actually a `td`-element isn't affected by `margin`. Are you sure this is the right CSS property to tweak?

Comment: category-right-margin can also be removed?

Comment: yes its working fine i am able to add margin to td

Comment: @user2787474 sure, a class can be removed, did you take a look at the jQ method `removeClass()` it's the first Google result if you search for `jquery how to remove a class` ...

Comment: can we able to remove class of the last td element on the basis of table id?

Comment: @user2787474 Are you sure? All table elements except for `table` itself do not have a concept of margins, [see this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xX5nq/).

Comment: category-right-margin is the class for applying margin to <td> element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the last `td` using `last` , as you said you know the table `id'

```
$( "#mytable td:last" ).css("margin-right",""); 
//to change the css property
$( "#mytable td:last" ).removeClass('myclass');
//to remove last td class
```

Comment: as per your `can we able to remove class of the last td element on the basis of table id?` , i updated above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table.category_list').find('td').eq(-1).css('margin-right', '');
```

This should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('table.category_list tr').each(function() {
      var lasttd=  $(this).find(':last-child');
      lasttd.css({margin-right:''});
});
```